# What is the difference between publications and pure publications?

Tags: publications, professorship, publishers, online-publication

I saw there are two sectors named 'publications' and 'pure publications' in some lab home pages. What is the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is related to the Max Planck Institutes, it might be this: https://www.biochem.mpg.de/878470/pubman

PuRe is a repository. In that case, "PuRe Publication" is just a special form of publication. Your capitalization in the question doesn't give much of a hint, however.

Comment: PuRe is used by other institutions than the MPG as well.